# Get extended/full text tweets in Twitter API v2

Tags: node.js, twitter, postman

The new Twitter v2 API was just released a couple of weeks ago, so this may just be an issue of the documentation not being done quite yet.

What I am trying to do is search recent tweets for "puppies" and return all that have some kind of media attached. However, when I run this search in Postman, not all of the returned tweets have `attachments.media_keys`. I noticed that the ones that do not have `attachments.media_keys` are tweets whose text ends in ellipses `...`. I understand that in the v1.1 API, this issue is solved by specifying `tweet_mode=extended` in the query params or `tweet.fields=extended_tweet`. However, these do not seem to work in the v2 API and I have not seen any documentation about getting the full text of tweets (and the associated attachments). Does anyone know how to do this in v2?

My Postman query url: "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=has:media puppies&tweet.fields=attachments&expansions=attachments.media_keys&media.fields=duration_ms,height,media_key,preview_image_url,public_metrics,type,url,width"

In my app, I am using Node.js Axios to perform the query:

```js
var axios = require('axios');

var config = {
  method: 'get',
  url: 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=has:media puppies&tweet.fields=attachments&expansions=attachments.media_keys&media.fields=duration_ms,height,media_key,preview_image_url,public_metrics,type,url,width',
  headers: { 
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {{my berarer token}}', 
  }
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Great question, thank you. We’re [discussing this on the Twitter Developer forums](https://twittercommunity.com/t/will-extended-tweet-text-be-available-in-sample-stream-and-tweet-lookup/141073) as well.

In v2 of the API we have eliminated the notion of an “extended Tweet” since we assume that all new apps understand the concept of 280 characters, so the complete text is in the Tweet text field.

The difference you’re finding is in retweets or quoted Tweets where the embedded text is truncated. This is (perhaps surprisingly) the same as v1.1 and the former premium and enterprise APIs as well. We are investigating whether to modify this, and the implications in doing so.

I don’t for any means want to take traffic away from Stack, but you might find more ongoing updates and information on our developer forums. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, so unless quoted / retweet / reply a bare tweet should be complete!

Answer (score 8):

As of July, 2021, for sure this "problem" or strange behavior concerns retweets.

To get full text of a retweet while getting recent tweets for a user I did the following trick:

First I get recent tweets for a user following [docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-users-id-tweets):

```
curl "https://api.twitter.com/2/users/2244994945/tweets?expansions=attachments.poll_ids,attachments.media_keys,author_id,entities.mentions.username,geo.place_id,in_reply_to_user_id,referenced_tweets.id,referenced_tweets.id.author_id&tweet.fields=attachments,author_id,context_annotations,conversation_id,created_at,entities,geo,id,in_reply_to_user_id,lang,possibly_sensitive,public_metrics,referenced_tweets,reply_settings,source,text,withheld&user.fields=created_at,description,entities,id,location,name,pinned_tweet_id,profile_image_url,protected,public_metrics,url,username,verified,withheld&place.fields=contained_within,country,country_code,full_name,geo,id,name,place_type&poll.fields=duration_minutes,end_datetime,id,options,voting_status&media.fields=duration_ms,height,media_key,preview_image_url,type,url,width,public_metrics,non_public_metrics,organic_metrics,promoted_metrics&max_results=5" -H "Authorization: Bearer $BEARER_TOKEN"
```

This is an all fields query (not all fields are necessary) but it is necessary to get `['includes']['tweets']` within the structure of the returned JSON data. This is the place where you have to look for the full text of a retweet - it is at: `['includes']['tweets'][0..n]['text]` while all the recent tweets (and retweets) are found at `['data'][0..n]['text']`.

Then you have to match the shortened retweets from the `['data']` with those from the `['includes']['tweets']`. I do it using `['data'][n]['referenced_tweets'][0]['id']` which should match `['includes']['tweets'][m]['id]`. where `n` and `m` are some indexes.

To be 100% safe you can check if `['data'][n]['referenced_tweets'][0]['id']` has a matching key/value pair: `type: retweet` (suggesting that this is really a retweet reference), but for me the `0` index works in all checked cases so not to complicate things more I left it this way for now :)

If that sounds complicated just dump the whole parsed JSON with all tweets and check the structure of the data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer which is exactly the same thing that I'm doing right now, but another strange thing that I came across is that some tweets even in the "includes" section (the tweets that were retweeted from) have ellipses and in fact not complete. do you have any idea why is that happening?