# Getting the latest tweet/retweet and full text of the retweet (Twitter API v2)

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to get the latest tweet/retweet by appending all my tweets, but I can't get the full text of retweets.

```
tweets = client.get_users_tweets(
    id='xxxxxxxxxxx',
    tweet_fields=['text']
)

data = []
for tweet in tweets.data:
    data.append(tweet)

print(data[0])
```

Retweet:

[image]
[image]

Comment: So what do you actually get? Is it a retweet?

Comment: I get all the tweets on my profile, but the text isn’t full.

Comment: What do you mean by “the text is not full”? Are your Tweets original full Tweets, or Retweets (or Quoted Tweets)? Are you expanding any attachments?

Comment: You may need to look for the full_text field instead of just the text field. You may want to take out the tweet_fields=['text'] and inspect each tweet status and see what's going on.

Comment: Now I see, it's fully printing my tweet, but it can't fully print retweets. I edited my question.

Comment: Since you are using v2, you will need to add the `expansions=referenced_tweets.id` parameter to your request, and match up the data in the returned `includes` object to get the text of the original Tweet from the retweet. There is an example of how to do this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68453617/262478)

Comment: @AndyPiper thanks man! You solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using v2, you will need to add the expansions=referenced_tweets.id parameter to your request, and match up the data in the returned includes object to get the text of the original Tweet from the retweet. There is an example of how to do this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63540330/get-extended-full-text-tweets-in-twitter-api-v2/68453617#68453617)

Comment: Can you please provide an updated code? As in how did you made changes to get full text?